# Passing values to database from C# application form

Tags: c#, insert, sql

A trying to insert a couple of values received from  textboxes into a table in access database.
I have perfectly written my statement without passing value for the primary key in the table since its datatype is set to auto number.

Upon running the program. i click the button that runs the insert statement and i recieve the following error "NUMBER OF QUERY VALUES AND DESTINATION FIELDS ARE NOT THE SAME"

How can i fix this...?

please let me know if any further information is required....
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Have you listed the columns you're inserting into?

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)
```

You must do this if you are not inserting into every column, and should do it anyway as it's best practice.

Comment: sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Youth ("

       + "NumbersOfSport, "
       + "YouthID, "
       + "Price, "
       + "TotalCostOfTraining, "
       + "PercentageDiscount, "
       + "AmountDue"
       + "DatePurchased"

       + ") VALUES ("

       + toSql(qtyInt) + ", "
       + toSql(youthInt) + ", "
       + toSql(priceStr) + ", "
       + toSql(totalCstStr) + ", "
       + toSql(discountStr) + ", "
       + toSql(amtDueStr) + ", "
       + toSql(Convert.ToDateTime(purDate))
       + ")";
Above is exactly what the code looks like without values for the primarykey section How do i go about it

Comment: You're missing the comma between AmountDue and DatePurchased. It thinks you only have six columns.

Comment: i inserted the comma and i get another error that says "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "19/12/2009 4:08:02"". am passing the current date and time to the datepurchased column and its datatype in access is also set to date/time. which operator am i missing?

Comment: You need delimiters around a date/time. If my recollection of access is right, you might be able to surround the date/time string with # characters to make it a date time literal?

Answer (score 2):

You should post your query with a question like this, but i think i know what your problem is.

Since you're not using the primary key column and therefore inserting into only a subset of the fields, you need to list the fields you will be using like this:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('val1','val2',3)
```

You were probably trying to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES ('val1','val2',3)
```

Which will not work because your primary key field is auto numbered.

Try this:

```
sqlQuery = 
"INSERT INTO Youth (" + 
"NumbersOfSport, " + 
"YouthID, " + 
"Price, " + 
"TotalCostOfTraining, " + 
"PercentageDiscount, " + 
"AmountDue," + 
"DatePurchased" + 
") VALUES (" + 
toSql(qtyInt) + ", " + 
toSql(youthInt) + ", " + 
toSql(priceStr) + ", " + 
toSql(totalCstStr) + ", " + 
toSql(discountStr) + ", " + 
toSql(amtDueStr) + ", " + 
toSql(Convert.ToDateTime(purDate)) + ")"
```

You were missing a comma here: "AmountDue" + 
should be: "AmountDue," +

VB format:

sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Youth (" + "NumbersOfSport, " + "YouthID, " + "Price, " + "TotalCostOfTraining, " + "PercentageDiscount, " + "AmountDue" + "DatePurchased" +    ") VALUES (" + toSql(qtyInt) + ", " + toSql(youthInt) + ", " + toSql(priceStr) + ", " + toSql(totalCstStr) + ", " + toSql(discountStr) + ", " + toSql(amtDueStr) + ", " + toSql(Convert.ToDateTime(purDate)) + ")"

Comment: sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Youth ("

       + "NumbersOfSport, "
       + "YouthID, "
       + "Price, "
       + "TotalCostOfTraining, "
       + "PercentageDiscount, "
       + "AmountDue"
       + "DatePurchased"

       + ") VALUES ("

       + toSql(qtyInt) + ", "
       + toSql(youthInt) + ", "
       + toSql(priceStr) + ", "
       + toSql(totalCstStr) + ", "
       + toSql(discountStr) + ", "
       + toSql(amtDueStr) + ", "
       + toSql(Convert.ToDateTime(purDate))
       + ")";
Above is my insert statement as in the program code

Comment: that is without the primary key values. so how do i edit that section pertaining to what you have advised..?

Comment: i inserted the comma and i get another error that says "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "19/12/2009 4:08:02"".

am passing the current date and time to the datepurchased column and its datatype in access is also set to date/time. which operator am i missing?

Comment: Try to format your datetime as ODBC canonical like this: 
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:sss  so your example: 2009-12-19 04:08:02.000

Comment: Also: we can't really tell exactly what your toSql method will do with the DateTimebut you could also try something like this:
toSql(purDate.ToString) Then again, we don't really know what type or format purDate is...